# Bedeutung von einem Demonstrativpronomen

Tags: pronoun, demonstrative-pronoun

Ich bin beim Lesen eines Buches auf den folgenden Satz gestoßen:

> Für den Analytiker schließt er (Grundsatz der Abstinenz) die Regel ein, dem Patienten die Befriedigung seiner Wünsche zu versagen und tatsächlich die Rolle zu übernehmen, die **dieser** bestrebt ist, ihm aufzudrängen.

Ich verstehe die Bedeutung bzw. die Rolle des fett-markierten Demonstrativpronomens nicht.

Answer (score 4):

Das Demonstrativpronomen bezieht sich auf den Patienten, der kurz zuvor genannt wurde. Vielleicht wird es deutlicher, wenn man den Satz auf zwei Sätze aufteilt:

> Für den Analytiker schließt der Grundsatz der Abstinenz folgende Regel ein: Versage dem Patentienten die Erfüllung seiner Wünsche und übernehme tatsächlich die Rolle, die dieser bestrebt ist, dir/dem Analytiker aufzudrängen.

Comment: My understanding is that you can use the demonstrative pronoun when the personal pronoun would be ambiguous. In this case there are two people mentioned in the sentence, the patient (*er*) and the analyst (*dieser*). In formal English you can use "the former" and "the latter"; in less formal English you'd probably have to split the sentence in two as suggested.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort. Oh Gott, ich kann immer noch die Bedeutung des gesamten Satzes nicht verstehen. 

Also, "dieser" ist "Patient". Dann ist das Subjekt des Relativsatzes "die dieser bestrebt ist" ist nicht "die", sondern "dieser". Ich habe das Wort "bestreben" und den Ausdruck "bestrebt sein" gegooglt, aber ich konnte nicht finden, dass dieser Ausdruck mit einem Akkusativobjekt verwendet wird. Aber anscheinend ist der Ausdruck "bestrebt sein" hier mit einem Akkusativobjekt, nämlich "die" verwendet.  Wie soll ich den Ausdruck verstehen? Ich nehme an, dass "die" sich auf "Rolle" bezieht.

Comment: @Bandabi Das wäre vermutlich genügend Stoff für eine eigene, neue Frage, aber vielleicht so viel: Das Subjekt des Relativsatzes "die dieser bestrebt ist" ist tatsächlich das "die". Der Relativsatz hängt an "die Rolle". Vielleicht wird es so verständlich: "Der Analytiker übernimmt die Rolle, die der Patient verlangt." - "Der Patient ist bestrebt, dem Analytiker die Rolle aufzudrängen." - "Der Analytiker übernimmt die Rolle, die der Patient bestrebt ist, dem Analytiker aufzudrängen."

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Aaaaah, ich verstehe. Vielen lieben Dank für deine Hilfe!

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Noch eine Frage! Wenn „die“ das Subjekt des Relativsatzes ist, was ist der Kasus von „dieser“?

Comment: @Bandabi Hm, jetzt gerate ich tatsächlich an die Grenzen meines Grammatik-Wissens ;) "Dieser" ist Nominativ, was man an der Frage sieht."Wer ist bestrebt, dir die Rolle aufzudrängen?" - "dieser / der Patient". Wie genau die "Ankopplung" eines Relativsatzes an einzelne Satzglieder funktioniert, können andere vermutlich besser erklären als ich. Ich habe nur als Kind gelernt, dass es so heißen muss ;) Vielleicht möchtest Du zu diesem Aspekt eine neue Frage stellen, oder mal schauen, ob es schon eine passende Frage gibt.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Vielen Dank für die Antwort! Ich werde vielleicht eine neue Frage dazu stellen. :)